# Equivalent C code for templatized C++

Tags: c++, c, templates, iterator, void-pointers

Here is a bubble sort function I just wrote:

```
template <class iter>
void bubble_sort(iter begin, iter end, int (*cmp)(void *, void *)) {
    bool didSwap;
    do {
        didSwap = false;
        for (iter temp = begin; (temp + 1) != end; ++temp)
            if ((*cmp)((temp+1), (temp))) {
                std::swap(*(temp+1), *temp);
                didSwap = true;
            }
        --end;
    } while (didSwap);
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible for such a thing to be done in C. The comparison function works fine as long as it is not used with standard stl containers such as deque, vector, list, etc. But it is the `iter begin` and `iter end` that I am worried about. Since you cannot do pointer arithmetic with void, how can I accomplish this? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) is available in standard C, and has been for *decades*, would lead me to believe the answer to your question is simply "yes, its possible, because its already a reality". And to answer how you to pointer arithmetic with a `void*`. you don't. You write your function to require an "item size" and use that via math with a `unsigned char*` cast from your `void*`.

Comment: Wow how did I forget about qsort when I was writing a sorting function?

Comment: C would be nice, but I think I can already do it now that I see qsort. But I want to see your answer anyways. I did mention "Equivalent C code..."

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I kinda overlooked that you wanted to "port" stuff to C. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: You have hit the *sweet spot* where your code will only compile with C++ compiler and potentially generate more code (`template`) but will pay the price of the C version (impossible to inline the comparison unless the whole function is itself inlined), managing to get the worst of both worlds in just a couple of lines...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas and to top it off, the template actually only works for pointers, not for iterators in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this the way the [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) function does it, and pass the size for the type and size of the array, as well as the pointer to the start of an array.

```
void bubble_sort(void* begin, size_t num, size_t size, int (*cmp)(void*,void*));
```

Comment: @Smac89 I put in the syntax, as well as a link to qsort that explains the usage with examples...

Comment: @Smac89, Just so you know what to increment it by to get to the next element instead of, say, halfway.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly achieve the equivalent result using `C`. In fact, under the hood most of the code you have their will be using C language fundamentals, such as working with pointers.

As for `iter begin, iter end`, under the hood they are essentially C pointers. There is a built in routine in `C` called [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), whose function signature is analogous to the code that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
void bubble_sort(void *array, size_t num, size_t ptr_size, int (*cmp)(void *, void *)) {
    bool didSwap;
    do {

        didSwap = false;
        for (size_t temp = 0; (temp+1) < num; ++temp)
            if ((*cmp)((bool *)(array+(temp*ptr_size)), (bool *)(array+(-~temp*ptr_size)))) {
                std::swap(*(bool *)(array+(temp*ptr_size)), *(bool *)(array+(-~temp*ptr_size)));
                didSwap = true;
            }
        --num;
    } while (didSwap);
}
```

Although someone mentioned something about casting to `char *`, then incrementing, `char *` did not work very well for this, only `bool`.

This is how I call the function in main:

```
bubble_sort(arr, 20, sizeof(int), (int (*)(void *, void *))compare);
```